# Help in writing a IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide

I m embarking on a difficult journey to create/replace a IDE for one of the middleware products from Bigblue.

Thy have created a IDE based on eclipse and Its a PIA to use it and very very slow even on decent configuration machine. Problem is there is no alternative to this.But i m planning to create one.
So to start off i need to write a GUI in C++. I m planning to use Qt for this.
But i need to understand how eclipse generate aritifacts and such. There are some graphical elements in Eclipse IDE used by bigblue. I need to create exacltly those graphical elements in my IDE.

So its basically writing a eclipse IDE only in C++ , but for the middle ware product only.

Any guidance , suggestions are most welcome.

I know i might fail in this endeavor, but I would rather try and fail than just to complain about how slow the IDE is.

Thanks all.

Edit : I have been using the Eclipse IDE for 5 years provided by bigblue and its dead slow, I have to use their version because it has customized environment for middleware tool.
I m finally tired of it.
:(

Comment: If you do not know anything about implementing IDEs, this will take you several months to get anywhere near something usable. Are you prepared to put in that kind of time?

Comment: yes I m so tired and fed up using the crap from bigblue..
planning to make it open source..so others can help

Comment: Months?  Eclipse has been in development for *years*.  You're not going to get anything remotely close to the same functionality.  Have you considered just getting a faster workstation?

Comment: Your company is obviously screwed up (from your comment in an answer saying they can't afford a decent development machine for maybe $700).  Check your employment agreements and make sure you can open-source something.

Comment: @David : You are wrong..every company that uses this tool has this problem..and i knw this because i have friends there..
Does this mean all companies that use this tool are screwed up..

Answer (score 7):

#### Write a better Eclipse plugin?

Eclipse by itself isn't slow, and Java is fairly fast, so I have to think you would win by simply doing a better Eclipse plugin.

If you don't believe me or if I'm wrong then I have to think the back-up plan is to write a plugin for a different IDE.

Even VS has third-party plug-ins.

Comment: Any faster IDE than Eclipse..
I m sorry but I find eclipse very very slow..
and its not just me..all the people i kwn who work with this tool say it so..but we have no other option..

Comment: I tried to present both alternatives: (1) Eclipse is fast, the plugin is slow, or (2) both are slow.

Comment: +1  Try Eclipse in a clean configuration as downloaded from Eclipse.org. It works just fine.

Comment: Ok So when you say eclipse is fast , it doesn't require JRE correct?
i mean is it java based?

Comment: Eclipse is Java-based, so it requires a JRE/JDK.

Comment: It's a bit unnerving suggesting writing a replacement for Eclipse, while at the same time knowing nothing about it.

Comment: Eclipse is Java-based, yes, but it uses a clever application life cycle management system, so that it doesn't have to load the whole program when it starts. It's really amazingly snappy considering how much code is in a typical Eclipse install these days.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to optimize your running environment.

1. Buy more RAM!  A development machine for Eclipse should have 4 GB RAM. Working with less is a waste of time.
2. Optimize your Eclipse JVM parameters - lots of articles on that subject.
3. I found that Eclipse works more smoothly on Mac OS X and Linux boxes than on Windows. My guess is that it is probably due to the superior memory management of Unix based OSs. Personally, I often find myself running 2-3 instances of Eclipse on OS X and they are all running just fine.

Comment: Buy more RAM! A development machine for Eclipse should have 4 GB RAM. Working with less is a waste of time. (Company cannot afford )

Optimize your Eclipse JVM parameters - lots of articles on that subject.( tried this with all parameters , eclipse is still slow)

I found that Eclipse works more smoothly on Mac OS X and Linux boxes than on Windows. My guess is that it is probably due to the superior memory management of Unix based OSs. Personally, I often find myself running 2-3 instances of Eclipse on OS X and they are all running just fine.(Forced to use windows system for work :(

Comment: If your company cannot afford $700 development machines, then it sure can't afford the literally thousands of hours it takes to write a "tolerable" IDE.

Comment: If the company can't afford to get you 4G of RAM for your development machine, it can't afford to pay you.  Look for a new job.  If it's run so badly that they're willing to pay you and not give you a $700 development machine, I'd have no confidence in their future.  Look for a new job.

Comment: I tend to agree, however, you probably haven't visited India :-)

Comment: @David: i Agree with what u say..but just becoz the bigblue makes crappy IDE's doesn;t mean we need a 700$ machine..
thats ridiculous..
But anyways..ur lucky u dont have to suffer this

Answer (score 2):

Do not judge the entire Eclipse ecosystem by your experience with a single IDE based on it. The Eclipse platform is not slow in itself and modern JVMs are pretty efficient (although a little memory hungry). If the IDE you are forced to use is slow and badly designed, it is probably due to that particular IDE, and not because of Eclipse itself.

I have quite a few years of experience designing and implementing IDEs, and I can tell you that if you embark on writing your own IDE, you will need at least 3-4 people just to keep it up with the feature set found in Eclipse/Visual Studio/etc. If you write it only for your own use, you will find that you get very little time over to do real work.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is a wonderful "platform" for developing our own IDE.  That way you don't need to worry too much about the mundane things and you can focus on what sets your IDE apart.  A good place to start is the [Eclipse Languages IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/index.php?category=ide)

Answer (score 0):

The only practical way to approach the problem as described in the OP is to write your IDE features as an extension to an existing IDE framework. For a full-featured IDE, you'll probably be starting with one of the following:

- Eclipse

  - Cross-platform
  - Extensions written in Java
- Visual Studio

  - Windows-only
  - Extensions written in a .NET language and/or C++

If you write your own IDE from scratch, you'll spend all your time working on the core IDE and end up with a product not nearly as good as one based on an existing IDE. Use a profiler to guide your work and you'll find the extension plenty fast enough.

Comment: interested in this 
# Visual Studio

    * Windows-only
    * Extensions written in a .NET language and/or C++